# A metric on the set of closed bounded subsets of a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Define the distance from a point $p$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ to a *subset* $Y \subset X$ by $$d(p,Y) := \inf \{ d(p,y) : y \in Y \}.$$ For any $\varepsilon > 0$, define $$Y_\varepsilon := \{ x \in X : d(x,Y) \leq \varepsilon \}.$$

> [G]iven any two **bounded** sets $A,B \subset X$, define $$d_S (A,B) = \inf \{ \varepsilon > 0 : A \subset B_\varepsilon\text{ and }B \subset A_\varepsilon \}.$$
>
> 1. Show that $d_S$ yields a metric on the set of **closed bounded** subsets of $X$.
> 2. Show that $d_S$ fails to do so on the set of **bounded** subsets of $X$.

Regarding part (1), I proved the first 2 properties of a metric, but failed to prove the third, which is the triangle inequality. Can somebody help me by giving a hint?

Comment: Finding a relationship between $Y_{\varepsilon + \delta}$ and $(Y_\varepsilon)_\delta$ helps.

Comment: I have attempted to transcribe your images into the "text" format allowed here. Please see [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for further information about this. Also, please ensure that I didn't unintentionally alter the meaning of your question.

Comment: FYI, this metric is known as the Hausdorff metric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Use the fact that $d$ satisfies the triangle inequality to show that if $A\subseteq B_\epsilon$, and $B\subseteq C_\delta$, then $A\subseteq C_{\delta+\epsilon}$.

Comment: Ok I can prove this result, but I don't see how it helps towards the required result.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta: It implies that if $d_S(A,B)<\epsilon$ and $d_S(B,C)<\delta$, then $d_S(A,C)<\epsilon+\delta$, from which it’s a fairly small step to the desired result.